# again, little problem with regex

Tags: java, regex

So I have a little problem

Here's my text

```
AFTER_2011/03/01 GREATER_2004_NOT
```

I want AFTER and GREATER, so i have the following regex:

```
[A-Z]{2,}\\B
```

At first its okay and I get AFTER, but the second time i get the entire line.
i tried add '?' before and after to turn it reluctant, also i tried \G to turn it global.
nothing works for me. in other times i used regex it has automatically started searching where last stopped, but not this time.
any suggestions?

Edit: So here is the code i wrote:

```
 private void checkFilterNames(String[] sections){

    _validityPatt = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{2,}\\B");
    boolean foundName;

    for (int i=0; i<sections.length; i++){  
        _checker = _validityPatt.matcher(sections[i]);
        _checker.find();
        String currentName = sections[i].substring(1, _checker.end());
        while (!currentName.equals("ACTION")){
            foundName = false;
            System.out.println("checking "+currentName);
            for (int k=0; k<FilterManager.getNames().length; k++){
                if (currentName.equals(FilterManager.getNames()[k])){
                    foundName = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!foundName){
                System.out.println("no such FILTER/ACTION/ORDER "+currentName);
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            _checker.find();
            currentName = sections[i].substring(1, _checker.end());
        }

    }
```

So this is the code. I want to isolate AFTER and then GREATER. I had a little mistake before the first loop i get 'AFTER' and then i get 'AFTER_2011/03/01 GREATER'

Comment: Please provide the Java code involved. Your current regex looks like it would match `AFTER`, `GREATER` and `NO`.. but you say you get the entire line which does not make sense. It would help to see the Java code involved.

Comment: it is not clear from your problem statement what you expect the regex to return, nor is it clear how you are actually trying to use this regex.  can you please clarify? include sample code?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "at first its okay".  if you're running the exact same regex on the exact same text, you should get the same result each time.  If there's more code, paste it on in!

Comment: The anchor `\G` matches at the position where the previous match ended. During the first match attempt, `\G` matches at the start of the string in the way `\A` does. Also `\B` means it is not the edge of a word (underscore and digit is part of a word) which explains why it would match `NO` instead of `NOT`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very clear. You could try a regex like this

```
([A-Z]{2,})_
```

Answer (score 2):

```
currentName = sections[i].substring(1, _checker.end());
```

should be:

```
currentName = sections[i].substring(_checker.start(), _checker.end());
```

I tested your regex, it is fine. I think the reason you are getting the wrong string is because you're always getting substring from index of 1.

First iteration (assuming 1 based index):

- start==1, end==6   .substring(1, end)
- is 'AFTER' so you're good

Second iteration

- start==18, end==25
- .substring(1, end) is
  'AFTER_2011/03/01 GREATER' so end
  index is good, but start index    is
  not
- .substring(start, end) is 'GREATER',
  this is what you want I believe